# $GITHUB_OUTPUT - Directory nonexistent (Self hosted runner)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm trying to use $GITHUB_OUTPUT instead of set-output.

I set up a simple GitHub Action with a docker file based on the official tutorial.

```
# Container image that runs your code
FROM alpine:latest

# Copies your code file from your action repository to the filesystem path `/` of the container
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# Code file to execute when the docker container starts up (`entrypoint.sh`)
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And the entrypoint.sh is

```
#!/bin/sh -l

time=$(date)
echo "time=$time" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Executing this in a Self hosted Debian runner results into a

```
/entrypoint.sh: 4: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
```

Changing the $GITHUB_OUTPUT with the usual ::set-output works correctly.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecation of set-output was [mentioned recently (oct. 2022)](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)

> If you are using self-hosted runners make sure they are updated to version 2.297.0 or greater.

So check first the version of your runner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, the version of the runner is probably one issue.

The other is that the environment variables defined in the shell that creates and runs the container that previously `echo "::set-output..."` do not have access to GITHUB_OUTPUT unless specifically configured to do so. Moreover, the paths within the container are not the same as that outside, so the path in $GITHUB_OUTPUT won't be available anyway.

The fastest workaround is to add `>> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` on the docker run command itself, ie. OUTSIDE of the container, and just echo content in there to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $GITHUB_OUTPUT, I unpacked the arbitration by creating a temporary file.

before:

```
time=$(date)
echo "time=$time" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

after:

```
echo $(date) > time
docker build -t example:$(cat time)
```

The above method can be applied.